# How to detect orientation change in home screen widget?

Tags: android

I am writing a home screen widget and want to update the home screen widget when the device orientation changes from portrait to landscape or the other way. How can I make it?

Currently, I tried to reigster to CONFIGURATION_CHANGED action like the code below, but the Android didn't allow me to do that by saying "IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents". Can someone help me? Thanks.

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        this.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED));
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old question but there's indeed an easier way to do this than delegating the update to an IntentService.
The way to deal with orientation changes is to listen for configuration changes in the Application and broadcast an ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE to the widget.

**Add an Application class to your app**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // create intent to update all instances of the widget
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE, null, this, MyWidget.class);

        // retrieve all appWidgetIds for the widget & put it into the Intent
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetMgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        ComponentName cm = new ComponentName(this, MyWidget.class);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetMgr.getAppWidgetIds(cm);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        // update the widget
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

The method will be called whenever a configuration change occurs, one of them being an orientation change. You could improve the method by doing the broadcast only when it's an orientation change and not e.g. a change of the system language.
The method basically sends an update broadcast to all instances of your widget.

**Define the MyApplication in your manifest**

```
<application
    android:name="yourpackagename.MyApplication"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">

    <!-- here go your Activity definitions -->

</application>
```

Comment: This works, but only when your app is running in the background. As soon as your app is killed by the Android framework, it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

You probably shouldn't need to do this. You can use layout and layout-land folders to provide different layouts in each orientation via xml without manually detecting rotation. However, you shouldn't do anything functionally different in each orientation as a lot of devices can't rotate the homescreen and whatever features you put in will be inaccessible for them.

Comment: the problem with the -land and -port folder solution is that it often requires you to copy an entire layout file to make a few or in my case one several character change. that being said, it appears to be the only solution.

Comment: Sometimes you can control this automatically with resources (integers, styles, etc) that varies between portrait and landscape. You can even have in your single layout two parallel views that are made VISIBLE/GONE automatically based on the orientation. In your update method you fill in both and the widget container will use the correct one based on orientation.

Answer (score 2):

While I sorta agree with jqpubliq's answer, so long as you think about what you're doing and design matters properly, you are welcome to implement different layouts for different orientations. It's just going to be complicated.

The error message you received should be self-explanatory: `BroadcastReceivers` (like `AppWidgetProvider`) cannot register for other broadcasts. After all, a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` instance should be in memory for milliseconds, not forever.

Hence, to implement this logic, you will need to:

1. Create an `IntentService` that handles the actual app widget updates, and have your `AppWidgetProvider` delegate its work to that. [Here is an example](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/TwitterWidget/).
2. Create a separate `BroadcastReceiver` implementation, registered in the manifest to receive `CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` broadcast `Intents`.
3. Have that new `BroadcastReceiver` also use the `IntentService` (e.g., call `startService()`).
4. Have `IntentService` handle the updates for both orientations, emanating from both receivers.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Very helpful.

There is one problem with the third step in your suggestion. The Android spec said about ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED: "You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver(). "
That's the reason I tried to use registerReceiver in my AppWidgetProvider. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oops. Forgot about that. That puts more emphasis on jqpubliq's answer, then. To receive that broadcast, you would need to keep a service hanging around in memory indefinitely. That's bad for business, not to mention inevitably ineffective -- either Android or your user will kill off your service, like it or not.

Comment: The OP wants to get events about orientation change of the home launcher. Does ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED provides this or just the orientation of the device (not the same signal since home launcher can be set to not change orientation).

Comment: @CommonsWare How can it be, then, that Calendar app of Google gets notified about configuration change (dark theme on/off) for its widget, even if I close the app (back key or removal from recent tasks) ? What do they do to overcome it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: If I am the developer of a launcher, and I detect a change in dark mode, I'm asking all my app widgets to update. So, I would not assume that Calendar is doing anything special.

Comment: @CommonsWare So you think it's because of the launcher? I thought that widgets get this callback (of onConfigurationChanged) from the OS itself. If it's this way, isn't it a bug, because launchers shouldn't block how widgets change their content? I thought it's a bug (noticed that Calendar widget doesn't change on Nova Launcher, but not on Pixel launcher) , so I reported about this:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151648847 . You say that if it's a bug, it's because of the launcher? Which launcher app do you work on?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Which launcher app do you work on? " -- I don't. That is why I wrote "if I am the developer of a launcher". "noticed that Calendar widget doesn't change on Nova Launcher, but not on Pixel launcher" -- one possibility is that Nova doesn't ask the app widgets to update on a dark mode change. Another possibility is that Google has special Calendar hooks in its own launcher. But that symptom (works in one launcher but not another) suggests the problem is not with the OS or Calendar.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry. I missed the "if" word and was very curious on what you work on :) . As for the issue, do you think launchers should be the one in charge of telling the widgets about configuration change?I thought that such a thing should be of the OS, or at least be an option (meaning that you'd be able to differentiate where the configuration has changed, which would be a problem for auto-scheduling of dark theme on R.As for bug on Calendar, I think it has some coloring issues (on some cases it changes colors only of minor things, and forgets the cells colors). I showed it on the videos.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "do you think launchers should be the one in charge of telling the widgets about configuration change?" -- in principle, the OS could ask each app widget to update through the normal means of updating app widgets. I don't think apps should be trying to monitor for `ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` directly. I have never heard of Android telling app widgets to update on a config change, so my guess is that it does not do that... which would leave launcher developers as the ones having responsibility.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know now that it's how it works. Just asked your opinion. Do you think it should be launchers's responsibility ? When it's this way, widget developers could face bug reports from users telling them that the widget doesn't change to dark theme, even though it's not their fault.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Do you think it should be launchers's responsibility ?" -- `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. Given that Android's app widget support really has not changed much in years, "it is what it is", and so if the OS does not tell the app widgets to update, the launcher should. Actual launcher developers probably have thought this through more than I have, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, dark theme is officially out only since Android 10 (yes I know it was kinda possible before), and on Android R it might support scheduled switching. Before, users don't usually cause a configuration change so often, so it wouldn't matter much. Now it can be noticeable.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: No argument there, and if you want to try to convince Google to automatically update all app widgets on a dark mode change, you are welcome to try. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare I already did. It's on the link I've provided, because whether it's intentional or not, I think it can cause users to think it's the widget developers' fault.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 3.x and above, who has RemoteViewsService, can be used

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   //call widget update methods/services/broadcasts 
}
```

in RemoteViewsService childs.
If widget will not be updated, widget UI can be cleaned or just hangs and stop react on external events.

Comment: Lools like RemoteViewsService.onConfigurationChanged correctly called only on Android ICS (4.x). Android Honeycomb called onConfigurationChanged from time to times (unstable).

Comment: Also I have found that AppWidgetProvider on rotate event called method onReceive with intent.getAction() == "com.sec.android.widgetapp.APPWIDGET_RESIZE" but update not called. So manual update widget on this action will help to correctly refresh widget

Comment: Anybody has success getting APPWIDGET_RESIZE events? Tried to receive them in my AppWidgetProvider but did not (I enabled them in AndroidManifest). I am using API 8.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android API 16, there is a new override that receives information about widget options changes, mainly min/max width/height.

```
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)
```

When this is called, one can check current device orientation and update widgets appropriately, or "simply" call the onUpdate() method which will have to get orientation information.

```
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)
{
    int width = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int height = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
    int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) logWidgetEvents("UPDATE " + width + "x" + height + " - " + orientation, new int[] { appWidgetId }, appWidgetManager);

    onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, new int[] { appWidgetId });
}
```

The onUpdate() can do something like this:

```
int rotation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (rotation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{
    ... portrait ...
}
else
{
    ... landscape ...
}
```