# Android - How to get a widget to recognize when the phones orientation has changed

Tags: android, widget, orientation, intentfilter

I want my widget to update when the phones orientation has changed.  Before android 2.0 you could register your widget to get the intent on orientation change

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
```

but after 2.0 you cannot do it. Android Dev doc says:

> You can not receive this through
>   components declared in manifests, only
>   by explicitly registering for it with
>   Context.registerReceiver().

Good advice to try to register it, but you can not register a receiver in a AppWidgetProvider.

I just want to know when the phone switches orientation so I can show some text correctly to the user when I run low on vertical space.

Comment: Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435548/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-home-screen-widget

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the home screen does not necessarily change orientation. For example, the Nexus One has the home screen in portrait orientation regardless of the physical position of the device. You are far better served adjusting your UI to not care so much about orientation and vertical space.

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured as much.  I was trying the layout landscape stuff but still could not get it to handle my widget layout right still.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service and register it to the CONFIGURATION_CHANGED event, like this

```
public class MyService extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            refreshWidget();  // Code to refresh the widget
        }
    };

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(bReceiver, intentFilter);
```

`}

Comment: I think I am doing exactly what you've suggested: https://gist.github.com/daviddoria/80c9c5dc98913b54bf00 but onReceive is never called? If I change     private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED); to     private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.TIME_TICK");, the onReceive is called every minute. Is there something else I have to do to get the configuration change to trigger the intent so I can receive it?