# How to make Widget aware of changes in textscale?

Tags: android, android-intent, configuration, android-widget, android-service

there are many questions on SO concerning device orientation change - which might or might not make sense for Widget. I'd like to be notified about configuration changes concerning the textScale. (I am doing some calculations which font size should be best to use, and rearrange the layout a bit, to make it look nice in the widget).

Having said that, I was wondering what the best approach is. So far, I found that:

- There's an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED), that cannot be received by AppWidgetProvider ("You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().")
- Listing [android:configChanges="fontScale"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) to the Manifest, that's for an Activity, not for a Receiver (that is for Widgets...)
- Then there's a [RemoteViewsService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.html) that has a method [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)(...), but I don't understand yet, how I would make use of that.

Are there more alternatives to check? Do I need to employ the RemoteViewsService? Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this will work:

- You can't register a component that will likely be disposed of in milliseconds by Android. So you can't register the AppWidgetProvider because it just won't stick around in memory. You can however register a BroadcastReceiver by another component since the lifetime of such a registered BroadcastReceiver is tied to the object that registered it (see more explanation below).
- As you noted correctly the configChanges tag is for Activity's only.
- The RemoteViewsService is used when using collection views (list, grid...) which might or might not apply to your case? In any case it's only available from API 11 on so it wouldn't work on Gingerbread devices.

Option 1 does kinda work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435879/534471.
The problem is that the registered BroadcastReceiver is tied to the object that registered it. Most Android components (ContentProvider, Activity, Service) won't stick around forever but will sooner or later be destroyed by Android. Your best bet would be a Service with START_STICKY but as CommonsWare correctly states in his answer it's a messy and ineffective solution (and not 100% reliable either).

AFAIK there's no reliable solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did read the SO question, that you linked, and I thought I also mentioned that in my question. At least that was my intention. So thanks for doing that and summarizing available information nicely.

In my case, it's not orientation change, but textScale, but this is a difference that does not affect the technical solution. The problem I have is that when the user increases the textscale, some texts don't fit into their TextView any longer. I'll see if I can change the view / layoutconfiguration to accomodate that.

Comment: I removed the orientation change part because it's indeed not related to the question. textScale and orientation does make a difference because orientation changes can happen in many different ways, caused by user actions, triggered programmatically, triggered by sliding out the keyboard etc. It seems as if many methods capturing the orientation change might fail with one or the other trigger. Anyway that's not what you're interested in and  I don't have a solution for you problem, sorry.

Comment: I somehow worked around that problem by giving the textviews a "setMinWidth" instead of a "setWidth", still the view looks a little awkward, until a redraw is triggered through other means. Since I don't expect fontScale to change frequently, this is an acceptable compromise for me. Thanks for your help.